# C# Receiving console writeline in richtextbox from windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have looked at all similar questions. I cant seem to figure out why my situation does not work. I created a test app using the following class:

```
 public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    RichTextBox _output = null;

    public TextBoxStreamWriter(RichTextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _output.AppendText(value.ToString()); // When character data is written, append it to the text box.
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }}
```

My Form Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   
    TextWriter _writer = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(richTextBox1);

        // Redirect the out Console stream
        Console.SetOut(_writer);

        //Console.WriteLine("Now redirecting output to the text box");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Writing to the Console now causes the text to be displayed in the text box.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }

}
```

This works every time I click the button. Now the reason for my question is why does it work there and not in my project. I created a Youtube uploader app using API 3 it uploads completes but the console writeline show the messages but my richtextbox only shows my intial Video uploading message. Altimately I only want to capture the write for a couple of reasons Show any errors, Get progress to for progressbar and get video.ID when I call Console.writeline my richtextbox does not get updated heres the code being used

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Upload video to youtube
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lblstatus.Text = "uploading video";
        Console.WriteLine("uploading video");
        try
        {
            Thread thead = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Run().Wait();
            });
            thead.IsBackground = true;
            thead.Start();

        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = txtTitle.Text;
        video.Snippet.Description = txtDescription.Text;
        string[] tagSeo = Regex.Split(txtTagSeo.Text, ","); 
        video.Snippet.Tags = tagSeo;
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
        var filePath = txtPath.Text; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

        Console.WriteLine(filePath);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                //lblstatus.Text = String.Format("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                break;

            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                //lblstatus.Text = String.Format("An error prevented the upload from completing.{0} ", progress.Exception);
                Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        MessageBox.Show("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }
```

Comment: Remove this: `Thread thead = new Thread(...)`, make the Button.Click handler `async` and `await Run();` -- Aren't you getting an exception each time you try to use `Console.WriteLine()` after you start the Thread?

Comment: I just tried that I am not getting any cross thread violations on console.writeline.   heres the final console write Video id 'lLV44D_SDX8' was successfully uploaded.

Comment: What is *that*? Did you await the Task or not? Did it work as expected or not?

Comment: Missed the await after adding await I get a cant await void.    'private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //lblstatus.Text = "uploading video";
            Console.WriteLine("uploading video");
            try
            {
                //Thread thead = new Thread(() =>
                //{
                Run().Wait();'

Comment: Sorry not sure how to post the actual code to make it more readable

Comment: You have to remove the Thread, i.e., write: `private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine("uploading video"); try { await Run(); } catch () { // [...]} }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250168/discussion-between-user2180706-and-jimi).

Comment: Sorry about the delay just got a chance to get back on this so I rewrote the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to make the above code work so I went to plan B. I started with getting the Video ID only because I only get 6 tries per day I choose to use the Video ID as string. I eliminated the TextBoxStreamWriter class all together and went with creating a new thread and delegate. I will work on the progressbar value next. here's how I did it for anyone else who may have a similar problem.
Created a delegate to update my video ID Label as follows

```
public delegate void LabelDelegate(string s);

    void UpdateVideoID(string text)
    {
        if (lblVideoID.InvokeRequired)
        {
            LabelDelegate LDEL = new LabelDelegate(UpdateVideoID);
            lblVideoID.Invoke(LDEL, text);
        }
        else
            lblVideoID.Text = text;
    }

 void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(() => UpdateVideoID(video.Id));
        th.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);

    }
```

Comment: I would like to Thank jimi for his help in trying to resolve my issue. I am creating this with the hopes of creating a freeware app for others but with me only having 6 upload max per day Is there a way without making each end user creating a developer account without me having to pay for an extended upload allowance? I know screencastomtic allows uploads without  the end user having to do so? https://screencast-o-matic.com/screen-recorder?